# Know whether the file or directory having permission to delete it in c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, desktop-application

In my application, I'm trying to delete file from code behind but it throws the error called "accessed denied". Anyone can tell me that how to get whether the file is having delete permission or not.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can just handle the exception

```
try
{
    Directory.Delete(dirPath);
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
{
    //Access denied
}
```

If you try to find out before calling `Directory.Delete` there's a small chance that there's a race condition and something locks the directory which would cause your program to throw an exception. If this exception isn't handled the program will be in an unstable state.